# Clustering on MDS Data

Tags: clustering, multidimensional-scaling

I have computed a matrix of MDS distances using R's dist() function and then reduced to two-dimensional coordinates using cmdscale() function. If I apply PAM or k-means clustering (the choice of algorithm is not the focus here) on the coordinates, then I can get something that looks like this:

[image]

I have seen conflicting views on whether it makes sense to cluster based on MDS coordinates (like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/r-clustering-and-multidimensional-scaling), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394204/k-means-clustering-of-mds-data) and [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshanem/psy5220/daily/Day16/MDS.html#sammons-non-linear-scaling-method)) without a lot of elaboration about why not to do so.

However, what I want to do is look at how the coordinates group/cluster together and then compare the clusters against an objective grouping. Say, for example, I have four experimental conditions for the above data and then I want to compare the clusters assigned by the algorithm to which condition each data point actually came from.

What I have tried so far is clustering the MDS coordinates and breaking down the points in each cluster by which condition they belong to. This allows for a plot that looks like this:

[image]

On the x-axis are each cluster as they are shown in the first figure (with clusters 1-4 corresponding to groups 1-4 in the first figure's key). The y-axis then shows the proportional breakdown of how much of the data points within the cluster belong to each of the four experimental conditions (represented with four different colours). As each data point comes from one, and only one, condition, the sum of the proportions is 100%.

Essentially, if the points cluster in a manner that does not relate at all to some external/objective variable, then I would expect each cluster to be pretty similar in their composition: containing an equal proportion of data points from each condition. If the opposite is true, I would expect each cluster to be entirely made up of points from one condition (i.e. cluster 1 contains only points from condition 1, cluster 2 contains only points from condition 2 etc). Of course, there is bound to be noise so points are not going to group together so cleanly, but hopefully this gets across the goal here. The problem here is that this is really in the eye of the beholder: the statistical interpretation is very subjective.

So my question is what approach would you take to a problem like this? Is there a more robust way of comparing clusters to data points' variables? And if there is any elaboration on why applying clustering to MDS coordinates may be discouraged, that would be helpful too. Thanks!